# In Synfony how do I divide a list according to the statut of his creator ? Error : Key for array with keys "0" does not exist

Tags: arrays, symfony, variables, key

I'd like to display two lists of events : one list with events created by organizers with organizer status and a list with events created by organizers with member status. My conditions are like this : "if some event exist" and "if the organizer who created the event is an organizer (or a regular member)". For information, "organizer" and "member" depend on the status of the organizer. Because of the second condition, I had this error :

```
Key "organizer" for array with keys "0" does not exist.
```

I don't understand why... What needs to be corrected ?

Thank you very much for your help.

My **twig** file :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des activités{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div class="events">

    <div class="vr fixed-top start-50"></div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

            <h2 class="text-center my-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/titres/zpeak-sorties.svg') }}" alt="Les Zpeak Sorties !">
            </h2>

            <ul class="list-group">

                {% if events and events.organizer.status == 'organizer' %}
                    
                    {% for event in events %}

                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/flag_images/' ~ event.spokenlanguage.image) }}" alt="Drapeau {{ event.spokenlanguage.name }}" class="me-2"> {{ event.title }}
                    </a>

                    {% endfor %}

                {% else %}

                    <p>Il n'y a pas de zpeak sortie organisée.</p>

                {% endif %}

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

            <h2 class="text-center my-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/titres/zpeak-idees.svg') }}" alt="Les Zpeak Idées !">
            </h2>

            <ul class="list-group">

            {% if events and events.organizer.status == 'member' %}
                    
                {% for event in events %}
                    
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/flag_images/' ~ event.spokenlanguage.image) }}" alt="Drapeau {{ event.spokenlanguage.name }}" class="me-2"> {{ event.title }}
                </a>

                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}

                <p>Il n'y a pas de zpeak idée proposée.</p>

            {% endif %}

            </ul>
            
        </div>
    
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

My **EventsController.php** file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoriesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{   
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request, SessionInterface $sessionInterface)
    {   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('events', [$data]);
        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository, 
        CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository
    ){
        $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
        dd($events);
        $categories = $categoriesRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", ['events' => $events, 'categories' => $categories]);
    }
}
```

**dd($events)** in EventsController.php :

```
EventsController.php on line 45:
array:1 [▼
  0 => App\Entity\Events {#1026 ▼
    -id: 1
    -title: "Soirée à Belleville"
    -description: "Viens boire un verre, rencontrer des natifs et pratiquer l'espagnol !"
    -category: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Categories {#933 ▶}
    -spokenlanguage: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Language {#981 ▶}
    -address: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Location {#744 ▶}
    -date: DateTime @1665446400 {#1022 ▶}
    -starttime: DateTime @72000 {#1023 ▶}
    -endtime: DateTime @86340 {#1024 ▶}
    -organizer: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User {#996 ▼
      -id: 1
      -email: null
      -roles: []
      -password: null
      -gender: null
      -lastname: null
      -firstname: null
      -birthdate: null
      -occupation: null
      -photo: null
      -status: null
      -nationality: null
      -nativelanguage: null
      +__isInitialized__: false
       …2
    }
    -participations: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1002 ▶}
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello,
Could you use `{{ dump(events) }}`in your twig template. `events` seems to be an array.

Comment: I got nothing when I use {{ dump(events) }} in my twig template. However, I get something when I use dd($data); in my controller. Would it be useful ?

Comment: Could you show me your Controller, and yes show the `dd($data);`.

Comment: Yes ! It's been added in description.

Comment: Oh, it's an array, you need to use https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: Ok. So I use a filter instead of a condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can have many Events, so in your twig, you need to use a for loop.
Place your `for loop` before the `if`.

Something like this :

```
<ul class="list-group">

{% for event in events %}

    {% if event and event.organizer.status == 'organizer' %}

        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/flag_images/' ~ event.spokenlanguage.image) }}" alt="Drapeau {{ event.spokenlanguage.name }}" class="me-2"> {{ event.title }}
        </a>


    {% else %}

        <p>Il n'y a pas de zpeak sortie organisée.</p>

    {% endif %}

 {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

In case you are sure to have only one item, you can use `events[0].organizer.status == 'organizer'`

Regards,

Comment: Oh I see, I'll try it right now.

Comment: Ok, I tried this {% for event in events.organizer.status == 'organizer' %} but it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: I already used a loop in the twig as I already seen the documentation you sent. Thank you for this Yohann.

Comment: I read again your solution. I'll try it now.

Comment: Very well. It solved the problem ! :D Thank you very much @Yohann Daniel Carter.